# Determine on iPhone if user has enabled local notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5, ios-simulator

I'm looking for a way to determine if the user has, via settings, enabled or disabled their Local notifications for my application.
Here I'm not using push notification

Thanks.

Comment: @akshata Please accept if you have really got answers for your previous questions. Otherwise your chances of getting answers is less.

Answer (score 0):

Set a test notification with a fireDate in 1 second.
Check if it gets called in

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification)
```

Comment: This test doesn't help. If the user has disabled local notifications for the app in settings, they will still be delivered while the app is open.

Comment: Now 2 years later look at this better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051950/check-if-local-notifications-are-enabled-in-ios-8/26052687#26052687

Answer (score 0):

Before iOS5.0 Local Notifications was always available.

Since iOS8.0 exists way to detect it is disabled by user or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052687/751932

There are no public way to determine what you ask between iOS 5.0 to 8.0

Answer (score -2):

you can find out what types of notifications the user has registered for by calling:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

which returns a bitmask based on UIRemoteNotificationType;

Comment: this doesn't tell you if user has notification enabled at all, only what types he enabled. He could turn off notifications completely and this will still return 6 (in my case). Is there any way how to detect it more reliable?

Comment: Also, more importantly, enabledRemoteNotificationTypes tells you about the **remote** notification types that are enabled. @akshata was asking about **local** notifications. Unfortunately, there's no method in the UIApplication API that can show what local notifications are enabled.