# How to check if Local Notification is enabled/disabled?

Tags: ios, notifications

I understand we can check if a user has enabled/disabled Remote Notification with this code:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]`

But what about checking for Local Notification?

I don't find a corresponding property for local notification types, and I have verified that `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` is only for remote notifications.

And we all know, users can edit their Notification settings, which will affect both remote and local.

Comment: Possibe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644134/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-local-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I don't think you can access this information.

One way you can check if the user has notifications enabled for your app is to send yourself a local notification with a 1 second delay :

```
UILocalNotification *testNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Test notification";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

And check if you catch it in :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification) {

    // If you get here, notifications are enabled
}
```

All there is left is add info (e.g in `localNotification.userInfo`) so you can know in `didReceiveLocalNotification:` if you are handling your test notification, or if it's a "real" notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) isLocalNotificationsEnable {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
        return (grantedSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) ? NO : YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

<sub>Note: the if block is only require if you're targeting < iOS 8.0.</sub>