# Check if Local Notifications are enabled in IOS 8

Tags: notifications, ios8, localnotification

I've looked all over the internet for how to create local notifications with IOS 8. I found many articles, but none explained how to determine if the user has set "alerts" on or off. Could someone please help me!!! I would prefer to use Objective C over Swift.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can check it by using `UIApplication` 's [currentUserNotificationSettings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/currentUserNotificationSettings)

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){ // Check it's iOS 8 and above
    UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    if (grantedSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        NSLog(@"No permiossion granted");
    }
    else if (grantedSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert ){
        NSLog(@"Sound and alert permissions ");
    }
    else if (grantedSettings.types  & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert){
        NSLog(@"Alert Permission Granted");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps , Let me know if you need more info

Comment: this works great.  If the user previously denied permissions the type == none but asking it again wont bring up the request window.  How can I know if they previously denied it?  Should I keep a flag in user preferences if I asked already?

Comment: Note, that it is available on iOS 8+ only.

Comment: Note, this only determines if it is enabled, not explicitly disabled.

Comment: @jasonmccreary How do you mean exactly? How can it be enabled if its explicitly disabled? I thinking Im having this issue. I used the above code in this thread, but I do not get the wanted effect at all. I have made a thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766846/uiusernotificationsettings-not-working-right

Comment: Shouldn't the second `if` be something like if (`grantedSettings.types & (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert))`since the bitwise comparation between 7* (111) & 2 (010) & 4 (100) will result in 0. 7 is all permissions

Comment: further to what Benjamin said - `(grantedSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)`  will NEVER be true

Comment: I know the question asks for Objective-C, but adding a Swift version of your answer could also be helpful :)

Answer (score 23):

To expand on Albert's answer, you are not required to use `rawValue` in Swift. Because `UIUserNotificationType` conforms to `OptionSetType` it is possible to do the following:

```
if let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings {
    if settings.types.contains([.alert, .sound]) {
        //Have alert and sound permissions
    } else if settings.types.contains(.alert) {
        //Have alert permission
    }
}
```

You use the bracket `[]` syntax to combine option types (similar to the bitwise-or `|` operator for combining option flags in other languages).

Comment: If you just want to know if the user have selected "something" then:
`let active = settings.types.intersection([.alert, .badge,.sound]).isEmpty == false`

Comment: Your answer is the best answer Michal Kaluzny +1

Answer (score 9):

Swift with `guard`:

```
guard let settings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings() where settings.types != .None else {
    return
}
```

Comment: could you explain what your code does? if != .none { what? } else { what? }

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple function in **Swift 3** that checks whether at least one type of notification is enabled.

Enjoy!

```
static func areNotificationsEnabled() -> Bool {
    guard let settings = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings else {
        return false
    }

    return settings.types.intersection([.alert, .badge, .sound]).isEmpty != true
}
```

Thanks Michał Kałużny for the inspiration.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** Take a look at @simeon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879547/4034572).

In Swift, you need to use `rawValue`:

```
let grantedSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
if grantedSettings.types.rawValue & UIUserNotificationType.Alert.rawValue != 0 {
    // Alert permission granted
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `rawValue`s, I don't think there's any guarantee they'd never change. As @simeon says, use `settings.types.contains(.Alert)`

Comment: No idea @ChrisWagner. I took this from a book from Matt Neuburg. I don't do iOS (I was porting an Android app 1 year ago). I've edited the answer to point to simeon's one. Thanks for the downvote anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Using the @simeon answer Xcode tells me that

> 'currentUserNotificationSettings' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:] and -[UNUserNotificationCenter getNotificationCategoriesWithCompletionHandler:]

so here is the solution using the UNUserNotificationCenter for **Swift 4**:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (settings) in

        switch settings.alertSetting{
        case .enabled:

            //Permissions are granted

        case .disabled:

            //Permissions are not granted

        case .notSupported:

            //The application does not support this notification type
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this code is more precise :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) {

    UIUserNotificationType types = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];

    if (types & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) {
        NSLog(@"Badge permission");
    }
    if (types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound){
        NSLog(@"Sound permission");
    }
    if (types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert){
        NSLog(@"Alert permission");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a few lines to explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C + iOS 10

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {

        switch (settings.authorizationStatus) {
            case UNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:

                break;

            case UNAuthorizationStatusDenied:

                break;

            case UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```