# UIUserNotificationSettings not working right?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which Im using to decide if the user has given permissions for local notifications:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
if (grantedSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        NSLog(@"No permission granted");
        //IF AND ONLY IF alerts are wanted by raymio user! FIX
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Notice"
                                                                       message:@"You need to enable notifications to be able to receive sun alerts!"
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* OKAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Go to Settings now" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                                                         }];

        [alert addAction:OKAction];
        UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

        [alert addAction:cancelAction];
        [self.window addSubview:self.window.rootViewController.view];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (grantedSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert ){
        NSLog(@"Sound and alert permissions ");
    }
    else if (grantedSettings.types  & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert){
        NSLog(@"Alert Permission Granted");
```

Basically, it just dont work. I get "Alert Permission Granted" when the allow notification switch is clearly set to off in app settings. If i switch it to on, the settings dont change either. Below is the console output for grantedSettings. It stays the same. I have other cases where something is off. For now I am resorting to just removing code. I had to do this in the first place in case a user accidentally pressed cancel on the initial prompt (and yet requests alerts in-app).

```
granted settings: <UIUserNotificationSettings: 0x17042e940; types: (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert UIUserNotificationTypeBadge UIUserNotificationTypeSound);>
```

Any insight in this buggy area? Btw, I am running on 8.1. The need for this is not entirely the same on ios9, as ios9 will let the user be prompted for notification permission more than once pr device..

Comment: Where is `generatedSettings` coming from?

Comment: @CharlesA I missed one line, edited question

Answer (score 0):

I used the below method in one of my project to determine whether the user has given permission or not, or whether he/she actually turned off the notifications in settings. Put this method in Appdelegate and check

```
-(BOOL)notificationServicesEnabled {
        BOOL isEnabled = NO;

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
            UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

            if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
                isEnabled = NO;
            } else {
                isEnabled = YES;
            }
        } else {
            UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
            if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
                isEnabled = YES;
            } else{
                isEnabled = NO;
            }
        }

        return isEnabled;
    }
```

Then you can simple check with condition

```
if([self notificationServicesEnabled])
```

I hope this should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9, to check whether the app is currently registered for remote notifications, use this:

```
BOOL isEnabled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```