# how to check local notifs enabled on ios9

Tags: ios, ios9, uilocalnotification

I want to check if the user has enabled local notifications on his/her device. As of now I use iOS 8 and

```
 UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIApplication sharedApplication].currentUserNotificationSettings;
 return settings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
```

to check if the user has enabled local notifications or not.

But in iOS 9 this code snippet seems to be throwing an error. Though the `currentUserNotificationSettings` seems to be present in the documentation for iOS 9, I keep getting this following error

> -[UIApplication currentUserNotificationSettings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e920c0

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766846/uiusernotificationsettings-not-working-right/33777985#33777985

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9, to check whether the app is currently registered for remote notifications, use this:

```
BOOL isEnabled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: even this seems to be throwing the error -[UIApplication isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f6fe80

Comment: it will obviously crash in iOS 8. It works only on iOS 9+.